# Google Chrome - auto scrollbars not working as expected?

Tags: google-chrome, scrollbars

Google Chrome - horizontal overflow works as expected, but, vertical overflow is causing showing bottom scrollbar too?

```
Code on:
http://jsfiddle.net/5yfLgo16/
```

What is what I want? I am using JS to center div on page. I want browser to show  vertical or horizontal scrollbar, or both scrollbars when needed. In mentioned example, you can see that browser is showing both of scrollbars when it comes to ONLY vertical overflow. Max-width and max-height are set to 100 px, BUT, browser shows horizontal scrollbar even if width of my div does not get to 100px. It is showing scrollbar on 50px wide div, with ability to scroll for 8 px... That is 58px, still less than maximal 100px. This works ONLY if I force 100px width, or if div is not fixed. My div HAVE to be fixed, at the middle of a page, AND it HAVE to be max 100 x 100 px. User "gmo" is convincing me that I am wrong about my expectations about this problem. How comes then that there is no problem when overflow is only horizontal (bottom left example), and show only needed, bottom scrollbar, and when it comes to only vertical overflow, browser show both bottom and side scrollbar (top right).

Comment: In fact, that's the expected behaviour, scrollbars use body space and the body is reduced proportionally when are shown. If the horizontal don't fit when the size is reduced... must show up don't?

Comment: Everything else works as expected, but top right example, I believe. If logic is the same, you say so, if I overflow only vertical, vertical scrollbar will show. If I overflow horizontal, horizontal will show. If I overflow both, both will show. BUT, in my example, if I overflow vertical, both are showing (I would accept it if horizontal overflow is exact as width of vertical scrollbar, but it is not...). I still believe it is a bug, Googles, or mine...

Comment: I will bet that's yours... Remove the fixed position and make the test again.. or better, remove all style and leave only the essential.

Comment: When I remove fixed, it works as it should! BUT, I need it's position to be fixed, anyway... :)

Comment: Remove the `fixed` to understand how it works... Add the `fixed` when you know how to do what you really need. There's many examples on how to detect scrollbars and act accordingly, but the important thing here is, that the browser behaviour is the expected, the issue is on your css code that is not the one you really need. If you update your question and add what's your need, and why is not working, would be easy (or more at least) to find a workaround.

Comment: There you go... :) I still believe that there might be workaround, and that this is not expected behavior, because it is not constant. Browser should, by my opinion react exactly the same on horizontal (showing only bottom scrollbar) and on vertical (showing only side scrollbar) overflow.